# How to trigger animation on state change with styled-components in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, styled-components

I am trying to show a line of text that is stored in the state as "story" and every time state (text) changes i want the animation to run. The problem is that the animation runs on page load, but not after the state has changed. I have looked into React Transition Team and some other methods such as removing and re-adding the animation from the css, but nothing seems very elegant when i work with styled-components.

What would be the most elegant way to solve this problem with styled-components?

Below is a snippet from my code with the styled-components animation and render method.

```
const keyframe = keyframes`
  0% {
    letter-spacing: 1em;
    -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
            filter: blur(12px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
            filter: blur(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
`

const Story = styled.h2`
  -webkit-animation: ${keyframe} 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
  animation: ${keyframe} 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
`

 render() {
   return (
            <Wrapper>
              <TextWrapper>
                <Story state={this.state.currentStory}>{this.state.currentStory}</Story>
              </TextWrapper>
            </Wrapper>
          );
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to force `React` to unmount and remount your component when the `currentStory` changes.

Try this:

```
render() {
    const story = this.state.currentStory
    return (
        <Wrapper>
          <TextWrapper>
            <Story key={story} state={story}>{story}</Story>
          </TextWrapper>
        </Wrapper>
      );
```

As the `key` changes, React treats each one as a new component.

Here's a quick'n'dirty [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-spence-wv6om)